# registro con PDO

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

tengo este error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

código de insersión

```
$adam2=Conexion::conectar();


    $fech = $_POST['fech'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];
    $ced  = $_POST['ced'];
    $nom  = $_POST['nom'];
    $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
    $fechRegistro = date('Y-m-d');

    // echo $nom;


    $registro = "INSERT INTO marcaje (fechEntrada, horaEntrada, cedula, nombre, cargo, horaRevista) VALUES (:fech, :hora, :ced, :nom, :cargo, :fechRegistro)";
    $resultado = $conn->prepare($registro);
    $resultado->execute(array(":fech"=>$fech, ":hora"=>$hora, ":ced"=>$ced, ":nom"=>$nom, ":cargo"=>$cargo, ":fechRegistro"=>$fechRegistro));

    echo "Registro Insertado";
    $resultado->closeCursor();
```

y este es el codigo de la conexion

```
class Conexion {
         public static function conectar(){

        try{

          $conn=new PDO('mssql:host=192.168.20.219; dbname=Intranet', 'adam', 'pass');

          $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          // $conect->exec("SET CHARACTER UTF8");




        }catch(Exception $e){

          die ("Error " . $e->getMessage());
          echo "Línea del Error " . $e->getLine();

        }

        return $conn;

      }

    }
```

me pueden ayudar?

Comment: La variable `$conn` no esta definida.  Deberia ser: `$adam2->prepare($registro);`

Comment: pero **$conn** es la que conecta con la base de datos y **$adam2** es la que guarda la instancia

Comment: por eso @JdavidBarajas si $adam2 guarda la instancia es entonces el objeto que deberías estar usando

Comment: `$conn` es una variable local de la clase Conexion.  `$adam2` es la instancia que vas a usar.

Comment: como ya te comentaron debería ser $adam2->prepare($registro);

Comment: estas bajo un escenario de un método estático que guarda su relación con la clase Conexion entonces $adam2 ha adquirido su calidad de objeto asociado a la funcionalidad de conexión

Comment: lo cambie y me sigue saliendo error

Comment: Es el mismo error?

Comment: resuelto .. gracias a todos